# third dimension must be 3 or 4 in matplotlib while i want to save 2

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib, scipy

I have an image converted from `rgb` to `L*a*b` space.

I can save L part separately but not `ab` part together.

`plt.imsave(path,ab_part)` gives error. The last dimension should be 3 or 4
where in my case: `ab_part.ndim=3` and `ab_part.shape=a x b x 2` one dimension is saved as L part.

So how can I save it? I have also tried to save as `savefig` after doing `plt.figure.fromarray('.')`

So how can I save it as image or if not then a flattened array would be ok. any suggestion?

p.s. Please suggest only scipy, numpy, matplotlib but not cv2

Comment: I asked this question months ago, but saw it negatively marked today, why? is it not a legit question, not detailed, do not show what I tried? Still no comment so that I can correct myself. Or just because someone just didn't like it because of no reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to save is not an image (at least, not one with a common file format), it's just data. Use [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), or even just the builtin `pickle` module, to save arrays.

Comment: So basically I am saving it as npy data in intermediate stages now and then form and later load from hdf5 dataset. Thanks @Eric